# Beyond Compare 3 new line without changing other side

Tags: newline, beyondcompare

how to move part of the text in one side to the new line without changing another side with blank lane ...

lets say i have one side:

```
<p>Test <i>description</i></p>
        </p>
```

and another side:

```
<p>Test <i>description</i></p>            </p>
```

if im just using <ENTER> then i receive blank row in window 1

in window 2 i want move

```
            </p>
```

to the new line without changes in window 1

ctrl/shift + enter doesn't do what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the left side (for example) at the line of interest and select "Align with.." (F7). Then click on a line in the right side. The two lines will now be aligned, i.e. side by side.